# MacBook autofills name fields with someone else's name

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, contacts

I have a brand new MacBook Pro. When I first started the computer and set it up, it asked for my name, but the field was already auto-filled with my brother's name.

When I install software, when there is a name field (such as for registration), my brother's name is auto-filled there. My brother hasn't lived here in over 10 years and this computer is brand new, he has never used it or even seen it.

Why would my computer be populating fields with his name?

Answer (score 3):

This likely pertains to the Address Book card marked as "me". Launch the Address Book application (from Spotlight, Finder, Launchpad, or the Dock), create or locate your own card, and choose the Card > Make This My Card menu item.

This could've originally happened if you or someone else created an Address Book card for your brother and marked it as "me", or if you copied Address Book data from another computer belonging to your brother.